# Minimum number of adjacent swaps required to bring largest element to the center of the matrix

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix

We have a matrix of m rows and n columns, for even values of both m and n we have 4 centers. We need to find minimum no. of swaps required to bring the largest element to the center of the matrix. Swaps can be made with horizontally and vertically adjacent elements.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        while (t-- > 0) {
            int m = sc.nextInt();
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            int[][] arr = new int[m][n];
            int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Integer> y = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
               for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                   arr[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
                   if (arr[i][j] > max)
                        max = arr[i][j];
               }
           }

           for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
               for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                   if (arr[i][j] == max) {
                       x.add(i);
                       y.add(j);
                   }
               }
           }
           ArrayList<Integer> centreX = new ArrayList<>();
           ArrayList<Integer> centreY = new ArrayList<>();
           if (m % 2 != 0 && n % 2 != 0) {
               centreX.add(m / 2);
               centreY.add(n / 2);
           }
           if (m % 2 == 0 && n % 2 == 0) {
               centreX.add(m / 2);
               centreY.add(n / 2);
               centreX.add((m / 2) - 1);
               centreY.add(n / 2);
               centreX.add(m / 2);
               centreY.add((n / 2) - 1);
               centreX.add((n / 2) - 1);
               centreY.add((m / 2) - 1);

        }
        if (m % 2 == 0 && n % 2 != 0) {
            centreX.add(m / 2);
            centreY.add(n / 2);
            centreX.add((m / 2) - 1);
            centreY.add(n / 2);
        }
        if (m % 2 != 0 && n % 2 == 0) {
            centreX.add(m / 2);
            centreY.add(n / 2);
            centreX.add(m / 2);
            centreY.add((n / 2) - 1);
        }
        int min_swap = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < centreX.size(); j++) {
                int swap = Math.abs(x.get(i) - centreX.get(j)) + Math.abs(y.get(i) - centreY.get(j));
                if (swap < min_swap)
                    min_swap = swap;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(min_swap);
    }
}
}
```

I am taking the input and then calculating the center of the matrix based on m and n which are the dimension of the matrix. It is passing the sample cases, but others are failing.

[Input Test cases](https://pastebin.com/GMVXW0X8)
[Output](https://pastebin.com/gARaRbV0)

Comment: Which cases are failing? Give a concrete Example. If not even you know any failing example, who should we guess one?

Comment: I have added sample test cases and output as pastebin links.

Comment: So and which one is failing? And what result would you expect?

Comment: @MrSmith42 The test cases are hidden and we need to find it out by ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code during my free time line by line

```
centreX.add((n / 2) - 1);
centreY.add((m / 2) - 1);
```

part of my code should be modified to

```
centreX.add((m / 2) - 1);
centreY.add((n / 2) - 1);
```

and wow! all test cases are passing.